# what happens when you instantiate only "new objectName()"

Tags: c#

I was just watching some videos on C# and I ran across something I did not understand.  Lets say I have a class

```
class person
{
    public string Name;
}
```

in my main code I place

```
new Person()
```

without declaring `Person New =`

Does it just create a reference of an object without a name on the Heap?  What is the perpose of doing this?

Comment: In this particular case, this code just creates new object on the heap. This object will become a garbage at the end of the method. We don't know the purpose, since only you know about video you watched, may be, this is just code sample. There's no payload here.

Comment: "This object will become a garbage at the end of the method." there is no guarantee at all for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It Creates an object but not assigned to any variable as Bawa said in the previous answer. Here i would like to include few more, that will explain how can we confirm that it creates a new instance:

Let me add a constructor to the class ; and define a new static variable; That is for maintaining the instance number;

```
public static int instanceConst = 0;
class person
    {
        public string Name;
        public person()
        {
            instanceConst++;
        }
    }
```

So that the `instanceConst` will increased by `1` for each instance. Now we can check them as follows:

```
int personInstanceNumber = 0;
var instant1 = new person();
personInstanceNumber = instanceConst; // personInstanceNumber=1
var instant2 = new person();
personInstanceNumber = instanceConst;// personInstanceNumber=2
instant1 = new person();
new person();
personInstanceNumber = instanceConst; // personInstanceNumber=4
```

That means an instance is created but, it is not used;

Comment: Like I pointed out, there is nothing inherently preventing anyone from using the created object, they just have to do it via some other means than using the reference returned by the ctor invocation.

Comment: does the new object get collected right after its fired?

Comment: the object gets collected when the garbage collector sees fit to collect it. this usually happens pretty soon after no part of the program knows about the object any more (it's way more complex than that though, the GC is an entire topic on it's own).

Answer (score 7):

it creates an object for you without a reference variable name. 
you create object without a reference variable name when you dont want to use that same object ever again.

by ever again - i mean  if you are not going to use that object anywhere else in the program.

Comment: This isn't true at all. This just means that you aren't saving a reference to the newly created object in the local scope. It does not mean that the object can't be used or is lost forever. See my example.

Comment: "The object will be created and garbage collected soon after since there is no reference to it. " you said this in your answer :) and let me look into example. thank you :)

Comment: yes, and then I added a caveat, explaining that this isn't necessarily true, we can only hope it is, because otherwise we have some issues, but there's nothing in the language spec that says it has to. maybe I'll reword my introduction

Comment: and definitely you are right about.. it begin destroyed at the end of the method .. it depends on the garbage collector when to destroy it :) so that's why i didn't say anything about it being destroyed. but how can you use the same object again.?

Comment: check my answer, I added an example (a trivial one out of infinitely many).

Answer (score 2):

The object will be created and HOPEFULLY garbage collected soon after since there is no reference to it. There is a caveat though. The constructor of this object can be arbitrarily complex. The compiler can't just optimize the statement away, because the constructor might be reflecting into another assembly, instantiating an `HttpClient` and firing the missiles. It could potentially even register itself as a member of some other class, or in some collection via shared/global state.

One thing you can be sure of though: If you see lines in a codebase that only consist of creating an object and then not assigning or passing it along inline somewhere, you have a pretty bad design smell right there.

EDIT: Here's an example of some really crappy code that would result in the object sticking around "forever"

```
static class GlobalState
{
    public static IList<object> GlobalStuff = new List<object>();
}

class Hacker
{
    public Hacker()
    {
        GlobalState.GlobalStuff.Add(this);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "hacker!!";
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new Hacker();
        Console.WriteLine(GlobalState.GlobalStuff[0].ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I like your use of design smell.